# How is a Ricardian Contract created? (file type, location, and naming convention)?

Tags: smart-contract, ricardian

The [Hello World](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cpp/docs/hello-world) tutorial defines [a sample Ricardian Contract](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cpp/docs/hello-world#section-hello-world-ricardian-contract) *(abreviated snippet below)*:

```
## CONTRACT FOR HELLO WORLD

### Parameters
Input parameters: NONE

Implied parameters: 

* _**account_name**_ (name of the party invoking and signing the contract)

### Intent
INTENT. The intention of the author and the invoker of this contract is to print output. It shall have no other effect.
```

However it does not say how or where to implement this example code.

1. Where should the Ricardian Contract be placed in your smart contract project folder structure? (e.g. in the same folder as the main `.cpp` contract file, in a subfolder, etc.)?
2. What file type should it be (e.g. `.cpp`, `.txt`, `.md`)?
3. What naming convention should/must it follow? (e.g. does it need to have the same name as the `.cpp`)

Comment: I have tried using it at compile time eosio-cpp does not recognise ricadian contract file

Answer (score 1):

1. Same as contracts (eosio-cpp will look for them when compiling)
2. .md
3. -rc.md

[**See Monstereos Example.**](https://github.com/MonsterEOS/monstereos/tree/master/contracts/pet)

There is a python script to create them [**here**](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/tree/master/scripts/abi_to_rc) from abi.